# Date format misinterception

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my form, I have a textbox and I a field called as "pickup_date". I am using jquery Datepicker. The date is in format of dd/mm/yyyy. But when I am trying to recreate the date using JavaScript, the date is incorrectly shown as the month and the month is shown as the date. How to fix this? My current script and values are below:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var dateStart = '07/03/2012'; //dd/mm/YYYY format
var timeStart = '09:00';

var startDate = new Date(dateStart + " " + timeStart);

document.write(startDate);

</script>
```

The above gives the date and time value as:

```
Tue Jul 03 2012 09:00:00
```

It is supposed to show up as

```
Wed Mar 07 2012 09:00:00
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You may show your appreciation by contributing back to the community, rather than utilising boilerplate characters at the end of each post.

Comment: It means, please don't write "thanks" signatures at the end of your posts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after messing around so much time, I finally came up with my own solution without having to use any external libraries of complicated calculations. So far, to me it looks as if its working perfectly. The following is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var dateStart = '07/03/2012';
var timeStart = '09:00';

var startDate = new Date(dateStart + " " + timeStart);

document.write(startDate);
document.write('<br />');

//declare an array
var my_arr = Array();
//explode/split the dd/mm/yyyy string so that we can collect it in our array
my_arr = dateStart.split('/');
//join the pieces of array in our mm/dd/yyyy format
var revised_date = my_arr[1] + '/' + my_arr[0] + '/' + my_arr[2];
//Generate the complete date
var startDate_revised = new Date(revised_date + " " + timeStart);
//Output the date
document.write(startDate_revised);
</script>
```

And thanks to all for their contributions. Really appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1):

dates are something of a weakness when working with native javascript. I feel that using a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) helps a lot with working with dates.

Answer (score 1):

Look up how to make TIMESTAMPS and work with those, convert your date to a timestamp, and convert it back to a date in your desired format when you wish to print it

functions in javascript:

get current timestamp

```
new Date().getTime(); //in miliseconds
```

print timestamp to string

```
//make formated date
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
// hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();
// minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
// seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

// will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

string to timestamp

```
//this only supports limited formats
function toTimestamp(strDate){
 var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
 return datum/1000;
}

function toTimestamp(year,month,day,hour,minute,second){
 var datum = new Date(Date.UTC(year,month-1,day,hour,minute,second));
 return datum.getTime()/1000;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply this to retrieve the correct day, month and year? I am currently messing with this and still it prints the month as Jul instead of Mar

Comment: +1 for all your efforts and the pointers. I have posted my own solution above.

Comment: @Denver, Yeah i think so, try to look up Date function on google, there should be more like .getSeconds. i don't know those out of the top of my head ^^

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses the American form of the date which is `mm/dd/YYYY`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) - this will give you a lot more control over how you manage date to string conversions so that your software can conform more easily to varying user format needs based on culture.

Internationalization and localization in JavaScript is still very problematic.